# Rotate image around x, y, z axis in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, matrix, rotation

I need to calculate a warp matrix in OpenCV, representing the rotation around a given axis.

Around Z axis -> straightforward: I use the standard rotation matrix

```
[cos(a) -sin(a) 0]
[sin(a)  cos(a) 0]
[    0       0  1]
```

This is not so obvious for other rotations, so I tried building a homography, as explained on Wikipedia:

```
H = R - t n^T / d
```

I tried with a simple rotation around the X axis, and assuming the distance between the camera and the image is twice the image height.

R is the standard rotation matrix

```
[1      0       0]
[0 cos(a) -sin(a)]
[0 sin(a)  cos(a)]
```

n is `[0 0 1]`because the camera is looking directly at the image from (0, 0, z_cam)

t is the translation, that should be `[0 -2h*(sin(a)) -2h*(1-cos(a))]`

d is the distance, and it's 2h per definition.

So, the final matrix is:

```
[1      0 0]
[0 cos(a) 0]
[0 sin(a) 1]
```

which looks quite good, when a = 0 it's an identity, and when a = pi it's mirrored around the x axis.

And yet, using this matrix for a perspective warp doesn't yield the expected result, the image is just "too warped" for small values of a, and disappears very quickly.

So, what am I doing wrong?

(note: I've read many questions and answers about this subject, but all are going in the opposite direction: I don't want to **decompose** a homography matrix, but rather to **build** one, given a 3d transformation, and a "fixed" camera or a fixed image and a moving camera).

Thank you.

Comment: How did you set your coordinate system?

Comment: (0,0) is upper left, x=colum, y=row. Basically, the image is loaded using cv::imread, and no transformations applied.

Comment: I think you should use the axis-angle representation and then the exponential map to obtain your rotation matrix [see this link for a brief explanation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axis%E2%80%93angle_representation)

Comment: Grazie mille, caro. :-) But i'm trying to keep it simple, and only use a 3x3 matrix for the whole transformation. Maybe I've found something here: http://jepsonsblog.blogspot.in/2012/11/rotation-in-3d-using-opencvs.html

Comment: di niente, but in that way (using yaw, pitch and roll) you can stuck in the [gimbal lock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal_lock).

Use the exponential map to avoid this problem. You need only the rotation axis (a unit vector for example (1,0,0) if you want to rotate around the x axis) and an angle.

Comment: and in OpenCV the map function is for free using the [cv::Rodrigues](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#rodrigues) function

Comment: Whatever. I already have a rotation matrix, what I'm missing is the 2d<->3d transformation to apply before and after the rotation. The link above has some example code, which is probably wrong.

Comment: before the transformation a pixel (u,v) become a point (x=u, y=v, z=0)
after a point (x,y,z) become a pixel (u=x, v=y). 
Start from the farther point...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally found a way, thanks to this post: https://plus.google.com/103190342755104432973/posts/NoXQtYQThgQ

I let OpenCV calculate the matrix for me, but I'm doing the perspective transform myself (found it easier to implement than putting everything into a cv::Mat)

```
float rotx, roty, rotz; // set these first
int f = 2; // this is also configurable, f=2 should be about 50mm focal length

int h = img.rows;
int w = img.cols;

float cx = cosf(rotx), sx = sinf(rotx);
float cy = cosf(roty), sy = sinf(roty);
float cz = cosf(rotz), sz = sinf(rotz);

float roto[3][2] = { // last column not needed, our vector has z=0
    { cz * cy, cz * sy * sx - sz * cx },
    { sz * cy, sz * sy * sx + cz * cx },
    { -sy, cy * sx }
};

float pt[4][2] = {{ -w / 2, -h / 2 }, { w / 2, -h / 2 }, { w / 2, h / 2 }, { -w / 2, h / 2 }};
float ptt[4][2];
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    float pz = pt[i][0] * roto[2][0] + pt[i][1] * roto[2][1];
    ptt[i][0] = w / 2 + (pt[i][0] * roto[0][0] + pt[i][1] * roto[0][1]) * f * h / (f * h + pz);
    ptt[i][1] = h / 2 + (pt[i][0] * roto[1][0] + pt[i][1] * roto[1][1]) * f * h / (f * h + pz);
}

cv::Mat in_pt = (cv::Mat_<float>(4, 2) << 0, 0, w, 0, w, h, 0, h);
cv::Mat out_pt = (cv::Mat_<float>(4, 2) << ptt[0][0], ptt[0][1],
    ptt[1][0], ptt[1][1], ptt[2][0], ptt[2][1], ptt[3][0], ptt[3][1]);

cv::Mat transform = cv::getPerspectiveTransform(in_pt, out_pt);

cv::Mat img_in = img.clone();
cv::warpPerspective(img_in, img, transform, img_in.size());
```