# Create a transparent image in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to rotate an image in x, y and z axis as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19093728/rotate-image-around-x-y-z-axis-in-opencv).
The image should not be cropped while rotating So I am doing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22041699/rotate-an-image-without-cropping-in-opencv-in-c)

```
Mat src = imread("path");
int diagonal = (int)sqrt(src.cols*src.cols+src.rows*src.rows);
int newWidth = diagonal;
int newHeight =diagonal;

Mat targetMat(newWidth, newHeight, src.type());
```

I am creating a bigger image targetMat. The input image is a png image.
But I want this image as a transparent image. So I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18491998/creating-transparent-image-in-opencv-c)

`Mat targetMat(newWidth, newHeight, src.type(), cv::Scalar(0,0,0,0));`

But the output image was [image: outputimage]

What I need is [image: transparent image] (Transparent image is here)

So what change do I have to do?

Comment: The problem is, that your input image is type `CV_8UC3` but you need `CV_8UC4` to use the alpha channel. So try `Mat targetMat(newWidth, newHeight, CV_8UC4, cv::Scalar(0,0,0,0));` or cvtColor of src before creation of new mat

Comment: @Micka So what can I do? because my input image is not CV_8UC4. I can't change the line src.type() to CV_8UC4 while initializing Mat since I am trying to rotate the input image. Can I do 
cvtColor( src,dst, CV_BGR2BGRA ); ???

Comment: I tried  cvtColor( src,src, CV_BGR2BGRA ); but gives error...

Comment: your input image has an alpha channel? look at imread flags, there is a flag to load the image in original type and color instead of alwaya reading as 8UC3. if your input image file hast no alpha channel, use cvtColor with BGR2BGRA flag

Comment: did you test whether an input was loaded successfully by calling imshow or testing that src.empty() is false?

Comment: @Micka The error is from some other part of the code. I am also trying to blend this image to a video. The error will be fro this part. Give your comment as an answer, so that I can approve. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is, that your input image is type `CV_8UC3` but you need `CV_8UC4` to use the alpha channel. So try `Mat targetMat(newHeight, newWidth, CV_8UC4, cv::Scalar(0,0,0,0));` or cvtColor of src before creation of new mat

To use your original image, there are two possibilities:

1. use `cv::cvtColor(src, src, CV_BGR2BGRA)` (and adjust later code to use a 4 channel matrix - cv::Vec4b instead of cv::Vec3b etc)
2. if your input file is a .png with alpha channel you can use the CV_LOAD_IMAGE_ANYDEPTH (hope this is the right one) flag to load it as a `CV_xxC4` image (might be 16 bit too) and to use the original alpha values.

Comment: with this flag CV_LOAD_IMAGE_ANYDEPTH  . we can add Alpha channel on Png? currently i am getting blue background on png if i use flag CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED and then add Alpha channel on png